# Is this code a jQuery selector or anything other?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

What does this code mean?

```
var item=$("<canvas>").attr("width", width).attr("height", height)[0];
```

Actually I'm curious about this syntax:

```
$("<canvas>")
```

Does that means create a canvas element? 
It seems not a selector in jQuery, right? If I want to select a canvas element I should use

```
$("canvas")
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, it means to create a `canvas` element. The `jQuery` function is overloaded:

- If passed **a selector**, it selects those elements.
- *If passed **an HTML string**, it creates an element.*
- If passed **a jQuery object**, it copies that jQuery object.
- If passed **an array**, it creates a jQuery object representing those objects.
- If passed **an element**, it creates a jQuery object with that element.
- if passed **a function**, it registers for it to be called on page load.

Answer (score 0):

`$("canvas")` does indeed mean select all canvas tags.

`$("<canvas>")` means create a canvas tag and return a reference to a jQuery object that has selected that one, newly created tag. Notably it's not added to the document anywhere yet, so you'd really need to do something like:

```
$('<canvas>').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the [`jQuery()` method can be used to create DOM elements from raw HTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element).  This also assigns the width/height attributes to the newly created element.  You would indeed select it with `$("canvas")`.  Note that this element does not get attached to the DOM.

Comment: Also thanks to you,@Explosion Pills